# Sending a post request through ajax with data as json, but in the endpoint it is not coming as json

Tags: json, ajax

I am building a simple post request using ajax and nothing fancy about that:

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'https://nnn.beeceptor.com',
                data:{
                    country: "country",
                    customer_title: "customer_title",
                    date_of_birth: "date_of_birth",
                    education: "education",
                    email: "email",
                    first_name: "first_name",
                    institution: "institution",
                    last_name: "last_name",
                    pay_type: "pay_type",
                    phone: "phone",
                    way_of_contact: "way_of_contact",
                    work_experience: "work_experience"
                },
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(`success`)
                },
                error: function(data){
                    console.log(`error`);
                }
            })
```

Now I want in the endpoint that data that I am sending in the body to come as json.

How can I fix that so the data comes to the endpoint formatted as json. For tests you can use that endpoint to see the format in which the data is coming. Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I was able to come with an answer. On the ajax request was needed to define the content in the header as follows:

```
 headers: {
                    "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8" // Add this line
                },
```

and in the data attribute:

```
data: JSON.stringify(data_object)
```

That solved my problem